# create waveform canvas and upload it as png to server / folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I am working on script that converts audio into a waveform using canvas and then uploads it to server as png. I got the javascript to create the waveform and it looks great, I am just trying to now figure out how to take that canvas amd upload it to server as png using toDataUrl(); and Ajax. For some reason it is not uploading to server.

[image]

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
// AUDIO CONTEXT
window.AudioContext = (window.AudioContext || 
window.webkitAudioContext || 
window.mozAudioContext || 
window.oAudioContext || 
window.msAudioContext);

if (!AudioContext) alert('This site cannot be run in your Browser. Try a recent Chrome or Firefox. ');

var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var currentBuffer  = null;

// CANVAS
var canvasWidth = canvasWidth = 500,  canvasHeight = 50 ;
var newCanvas   = createCanvas (canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
var context     = null;

window.onload = appendCanvas;
function appendCanvas() { document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);
                          context = newCanvas.getContext('2d'); }

// MUSIC LOADER + DECODE
function loadMusic(url) {   
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open( "GET", url, true );
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";    
    req.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
          if (req.readyState == 4) {
             if(req.status == 200)
                  audioContext.decodeAudioData(req.response, 
                    function(buffer) {
                             currentBuffer = buffer;
                             displayBuffer(buffer);
                    }, onDecodeError);
             else
                  alert('error during the load.Wrong url or cross origin issue');
          }
    } ;
    req.send();
}

function onDecodeError() {  alert('error while decoding your file.');  }

// MUSIC DISPLAY
function displayBuffer(buff /* is an AudioBuffer */) {

  var drawLines = 10000;
   var leftChannel = buff.getChannelData(0); // Float32Array describing left channel     
   var lineOpacity = canvasWidth / leftChannel.length  ;      
   context.save();
   context.fillStyle = '#000' ;
   context.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight );
   context.strokeStyle = 'lightgreen';
   context.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
   context.translate(0,canvasHeight / 2);
   context.globalAlpha = 0.1 ;
   context.lineWidth=1;
   var totallength = leftChannel.length;
   var eachBlock = Math.floor(totallength / drawLines);
   var lineGap = (canvasWidth/drawLines);

  context.beginPath();
   for(var i=0;i<=drawLines;i++){
      var audioBuffKey = Math.floor(eachBlock * i);
       var x = i*lineGap;
       var y = leftChannel[audioBuffKey] * canvasHeight / 2;
       context.moveTo( x, y );
       context.lineTo( x, (y*-1) );
   }
   context.stroke();
   context.restore();
}

function createCanvas ( w, h ) {
    var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    newCanvas.width  = w;     newCanvas.height = h;

};

loadMusic('wavformtest.mp3');   

function uploadtoserver(myCanvas) {
    var photo = myCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');                
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'photo_upload.php',
      data: {
        photo: photo
      }
    }); 

}

</script>
```

**photo_upload.php**

```
<?php

    $data = $_POST['photo'];
    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/song");

    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/images/song/".time().'.png', $data);
    die;
?>
```

Comment: not uploading **HOW**? $_POST['photo']` comes out empty?

Comment: Hey Marc, The image isn't in the folder /images/song... plus it doesnt seem to goto php page

Comment: basic debugging, then: check the return value of `file_put_contents()`. never EVER assume success when dealing with external resources. just because the path "looks ok" doesn't mean it's actually usable. ditto for `mkdir()`.

Comment: Hey Marc, I am not sure if i need $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] i will try without that

Comment: without it, you'll be trying to create that dir off the root of your file system, where your webserver user ID almost guaranteed doesn't have permissions to be messing around with files.

Comment: Hey Marc, I see, I have never had to use it before when I did a previous upload script so I was wondering, I don't know how to do basic debugging ot check the return value of file_put_contents() so I will have to continue doing more research on the topics

Comment: `$result = file_get_contents(...); if ($result === false) { die("file_get_contents failed"); }`

Comment: Hey Marc, I beilive it could be somthing with my following function not sending any data to php   function uploadtoserver(myCanvas) {
    var photo = myCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');                
 $.ajax({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'photo_upload.php',
   data: {
  photo: photo
   }
 }); 
 
}

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`, then, see what's arriving at the server.

Comment: Hey Marc, for some reason I don't think its even posting any data to the server, something may be wrong on the javascript side / ajax request. I have written photos to same folder before using a different script so I know the permissions are correct.

Comment: I don't see any calls to `uploadtoserver`. you just define the function and then never use it.